# TortoiseSVN and local source code term

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm learning to use `TortoiseSVN`. When I get code from an existing source repository, it is placed in a directory on my local machine. That directory is then tied to SVN somehow. My question is, what is this link called? Is it called a link, or a mapping, or something else entirely. I'm trying to learn the terminology so I can find answers effectively.

Currently, I'm trying to communicate that a local folder needs to stop being connected to SVN via `TortoiseSVN`. I know that saying "Removing a folder from SVN" is incorrect, because that would imply deleting the folder in the source repository itself. Should I communicate to remove the mapping? Or what?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a local folder needs to stop being connected to SVN via TortoiseSVN

Unversion Working Copy

Answer (score 0):

There is not any hard and fast rule.Remove/Deleted is good.
This will help you: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-glossary.html